# Jquery Sortable find Draggable and Droppable Id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have following Code:

```
 <ul class='sortableLI'>
   <li id='1'>One</li>
   <li id='2'>Two</li>
   <li id='3'>Three</li>
   <li id='4'>Four</li>
   <li id='5'>Five</li>
 </ul>
```

if i drag 5 (UP) and drop b/w 2 & 3 so i need id of 3  and if i drag 2 (DOWN) and drop b/w 4 & 5 so i need id of 4.

How?

Comment: I mean when i drag From bottom to top so i get prev() and if i drag from Top to bottom so i get Next(). How can i catch the direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the answer :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sortableLI').sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var newP = ui.position.top;
            var oldP = ui.originalPosition.top;
            if (newP > oldP) {
                alert('moved down');
                var id = $(ui.item).prev('li').attr('id');
                alert(id);

            } else {
                alert('moved up');
                var id = $(ui.item).next('li').attr('id');
                alert(id);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class='sortableLI'>
   <li id='1'>One</li>
   <li id='2'>Two</li>
   <li id='3'>Three</li>
   <li id='4'>Four</li>
   <li id='5'>Five</li>
 </ul>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/147/

You need `prev` and `next` function of jQuery for this purpose.

Comment: My friend i think you didn't understand. I mean when i drag From bottom to top so i get prev() and if i drag from Top to bottom so i get Next(). How can i catch the direction?

Comment: Updated the answer. Is that you want?